# Create URL to open specific tab in a Menu

Tags: html, tabs, radio-button

I created a tab menu using radio function (see code below). Ths code requires now javascript but I am wondering if thered is a way to create a url with hashtag that will open that specific tab.

I tried [www.website.com/blah#idname](http://www.website.com/blah#idname) but that doesn't work. Can you help?

```
<style>
  /*
 CSS for the main interaction
*/
  .tabset>input[type="radio"] {
    position: absolute;
    left: -200vw;
  }

  .tabset .tab-panel {
    display: none;
  }

  .tabset>input:first-child:checked~.tab-panels>.tab-panel:first-child,
  .tabset>input:nth-child(3):checked~.tab-panels>.tab-panel:nth-child(2),
  .tabset>input:nth-child(5):checked~.tab-panels>.tab-panel:nth-child(3),
  .tabset>input:nth-child(7):checked~.tab-panels>.tab-panel:nth-child(4),
  .tabset>input:nth-child(9):checked~.tab-panels>.tab-panel:nth-child(5),
  .tabset>input:nth-child(11):checked~.tab-panels>.tab-panel:nth-child(6) {
    display: block;
  }

  /*
 Styling
*/
  .content {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 22px;
    margin: 0 0 25px 0 !important;
  }

  body {
    color: #333;
    font-family: 'Rubik-Light', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
  }

  .tablabel {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  
  .tabhead {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: 'Rubik-Medium', Arial, sans-serif !important;
    font-weight: normal;
  }


  .tabset>label {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px 15px 25px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: 'Rubik-Regular', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
  }

  .tabset>label::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 15px;
    bottom: 10px;
    width: 22px;
    height: 4px;
    background: #8d8d8d;
  }

  input:focus-visible+label {
    outline: 2px solid rgba(0, 102, 204, 1);
    border-radius: 3px;
  }

  .tabset>label:hover,
  .tabset>input:focus+label,
  .tabset>input:checked+label {
    color: #06c;
  }

  .tabset>label:hover::after,
  .tabset>input:focus+label::after,
  .tabset>input:checked+label::after {
    background: #06c;
  }

  .tabset>input:checked+label {
    border-color: #ccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
  }

  .tab-panel {
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  }

  /*
 Demo purposes only
*/
  *,
  *:before,
  *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  .tabset {
  }
</style>

<!-- 
  
  Radio version of tabs.

  Requirements:
  - not rely on specific IDs for CSS (the CSS shouldn't need to know specific IDs)
  - flexible for any number of unkown tabs [2-6]
  - accessible

  Caveats:
  - since these are checkboxes the tabs not tab-able, need to use arrow keys

  Also worth reading:
  http://simplyaccessible.com/article/danger-aria-tabs/
-->

<div class="tabset">
  <!-- Tab 1 -->
  <input type="radio" name="tabset" id="tab1" aria-controls="Competitor 1" checked>
  <label class="tablabel" for="tab1">Competitor 1</label>
  <!-- Tab 2 -->
  <input type="radio" name="tabset" id="tab2" aria-controls="Competitor 2">
  <label class="tablabel" for="tab2">Competitor 2</label>
  <!-- Tab 3 -->
  <input type="radio" name="tabset" id="tab3" aria-controls="Competitor 3">
  <label class="tablabel" for="tab3">Competitor 3</label>
  <!-- Tab 4 -->
  <input type="radio" name="tabset" id="tab4" aria-controls="Competitor 4">
  <label class="tablabel" for="tab4">Competitor 4</label>
  <div class="tab-panels">
    <section id="comp1" class="tab-panel">
      <h2 class="tabhead">Competitor 1</h2>
      <p class="content"><strong>Subtitle:</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit pellentesque habitant. Aliquam sem et tortor consequat. Arcu risus quis varius quam quisque. </p>
      <p class="content"><strong>Subtitle:</strong> Quisque egestas diam in arcu cursus euismod quis viverra. Fermentum et sollicitudin ac orci phasellus egestas tellus rutrum. Duis at consectetur lorem donec massa sapien. Nisl purus in mollis nunc sed id semper. Tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras. Nulla malesuada pellentesque elit eget gravida cum sociis natoque penatibus.</p>
    </section>
    <section id="comp2" class="tab-panel">
      <h2 class="tabhead">Competitor 2</h2>
      <p class="content"><strong>Subtitle:</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit pellentesque habitant. Aliquam sem et tortor consequat. Arcu risus quis varius quam quisque. </p>
      <p class="content"><strong>Subtitle:</strong> Quisque egestas diam in arcu cursus euismod quis viverra. Fermentum et sollicitudin ac orci phasellus egestas tellus rutrum. Duis at consectetur lorem donec massa sapien. Nisl purus in mollis nunc sed id semper. Tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras. Nulla malesuada pellentesque elit eget gravida cum sociis natoque penatibus.</p>
    </section>
    <section id="comp3" class="tab-panel">
      <h2 class="tabhead">Competitor 3</h2>
      <p class="content"><strong>Subtitle:</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit pellentesque habitant. Aliquam sem et tortor consequat. Arcu risus quis varius quam quisque. </p>
      <p class="content"><strong>Subtitle:</strong> Quisque egestas diam in arcu cursus euismod quis viverra. Fermentum et sollicitudin ac orci phasellus egestas tellus rutrum. Duis at consectetur lorem donec massa sapien. Nisl purus in mollis nunc sed id semper. Tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras. Nulla malesuada pellentesque elit eget gravida cum sociis natoque penatibus.</p>
    </section>
    <section id="comp4" class="tab-panel">
      <h2 class="tabhead" >Competitor 4</h2>
      <p class="content"><strong>Subtitle:</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit pellentesque habitant. Aliquam sem et tortor consequat. Arcu risus quis varius quam quisque. </p>
      <p class="content"><strong>Subtitle:</strong> Quisque egestas diam in arcu cursus euismod quis viverra. Fermentum et sollicitudin ac orci phasellus egestas tellus rutrum. Duis at consectetur lorem donec massa sapien. Nisl purus in mollis nunc sed id semper. Tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras. Nulla malesuada pellentesque elit eget gravida cum sociis natoque penatibus.</p>
    </section>
  </div>

</div>
```

Create a URL with a parameter to open a specific tab.